# What is the context of a task that is saved on stack when a task is blocked in VxWorks?

Tags: c, operating-system, vxworks, internals

What is the context of a task that is saved on stack when a task is blocked in VxWorks?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a facebook-question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30475/official-stance-on-facebook-questions-on-su . Tho i'm not sure so i'm not voting for anything. Also not to discourage the new user.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. When a task is blocked, the entire context of the task is what is saved. The context is technically contained in the TCB (Task Control Block) which is separate from the task stack.

Thus, a blocked task does not have a context, but it's state would be pended.